# Java streams collect function: property cannot be resolved [Compilation error]

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

This is sample code. prop used in Collectors.toMap(...) is showing compiler error: **[prop cannot be resolved.]**

```
//Some code here

Object param1 = someValueAvail;
Map<String, someConfigPojo> configMap = someValueAvail;
List<String> propertyList = Arrays.asList("prop1","prop2");
Map<String, String> propertyMap = null;
propertyMap = propertyList.stream().filter(prop -> configMap.get(prop) != null)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(prop->prop, getValue(param1, configMap.get(prop).getPathAsString())));

// Some code here                                   


private String getValue(Object param, String path){
    //Do some stuff
    return somevalue;
}
```

Comment: You need another `prop ->` before `getValue(param1` etc.

Comment: Shit man. So dumb of me. How could I miss that. Thanks Andy (Y)

Comment: [Explain it to the duck first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another `prop ->`:

```
Collectors.toMap(
    prop->prop,
    prop->getValue(param1, configMap.get(prop).getPathAsString()))
```

The `,` ends the lambda expression `prop->prop`, so the `getValue` etc is a separate expression, and there is no symbol `prop` in the enclosing scope.

Note that `prop->prop` can be written as `Function.identity()` too.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `valueMapper` as in:

```
Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
        prop -> getValue(param1, configMap.get(prop).getPathAsString()))
```